# Switch between components without url

Tags: angular

Is it possible in angular to switch between two components without the need for routes?  if there is how do i go about that please? I want to be switching between just two components and i don't want to use routes for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<component1 *ngIf="page == 1"></component1>
<component2 *ngIf="page == 2"></component2>
```

Where `page` is a field on the host component where you assign `1` or `2` to switch between the pages. You can also use `ngSwitchWhen`

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for a different approach.